# A simple iteration with if else

Tags: c#, if-statement, iteration

Iterating through an array of strings i want it to write a specific line if one of the elements coresponds to the condition. The problem is with the else condition. It is written as many times as the length of the array and i only need it written once

```
 public static void FindSandy(params string[] ocean)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < ocean.Length; i++)
        {
            if (ocean[i] == "Sandy")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("We found Sandy on position {0}", i);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("He was not here");
            }


        }


    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        {
            FindSandy("Bob","Bella", "Sandy", "Nemo", "Dory");
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can't know "He's not there" until *after* you have checked all positions; that is, once the loop has finished.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about if you just return if you found it?

```
public static void FindSandy(params string[] ocean)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ocean.Length; i++)
    {
        if (ocean[i] == "Sandy")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("We found Sandy on position {0}", i);
            // Found, you can return from method.
            return; 
        }
    }

    // Not found, write the 'not found' message.
    Console.WriteLine("He was not here");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to change your code to handle this is to create a variable that tracks the index where Sandy is found, initialize it to an invalid value (like `-1`), and then set it to the actual value in your `if` block (and we can also add a `break;` statement to exit the loop as soon as we find him).

Then, we output a string based on the value of the `position` variable:

```
public static void FindSandy(params string[] ocean)
{
    int position = -1;

    for (int i = 0; i < ocean?.Length; i++)
    {
        if (ocean[i] == "Sandy")
        {
            position = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (position > -1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("We found Sandy on position {0}", position);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("He was not here");
    }
}
```

The code can be simplified a little with the `System.Linq` extension methods `Select` (to select the name and then index) and `FirstOrDefault` which returns the first item that meets a condidion, or the default for the type (which is `null`):

```
public static void FindSandy(params string[] ocean)
{
    var position = ocean?.Select((name, index) => new {name, index})
        .FirstOrDefault(item => item.name == "Sandy");

    Console.WriteLine(position == null 
        ? "He was not here" 
        : $"We found Sandy on position {position.index}");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the keyword `break` to exit the `for` loop :

```
public static void FindSandy(params string[] ocean)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < ocean.Length; i++)
        {
            if (ocean[i] == "Sandy")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("We found Sandy on position {0}", i);
                break;
            }
            else if (i == ocean.Length - 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("He was not here");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you `breaks` the code in `else` section, never will finish the iteration, you might use `continue`

Comment: Ya, before edit your answer was gonna fail, now works ! Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

To solve your issue, you could add a new boolean variable (*e.g.* `weFoundSandy`): if you find an occurrence, set this variable to `true`, use the [`break`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/break) statement (to reduce the iterations of the `for`) and, at the end, use this boolean variable to determine which message to display.

```
public static void FindSandy(params string[] ocean) {
  bool weFoundSandy = false;
  for (int i = 0; i < ocean.Length; i++) {
    if (ocean[i] == "Sandy") {
      Console.WriteLine("We found Sandy on position {0}", i);
      weFoundSandy = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (!weFoundSandy) {
    Console.WriteLine("Sandy was not here");
  }
}
```

or, you could simply use the C# [`Array.IndexOf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.indexof?view=netframework-4.8) method, *e.g.*:

```
public static void FindSandy(params string[] ocean) {
  int indexOfSandy = Array.IndexOf(ocean, "Sandy");
  if (indexOfSandy >= 0) {
    Console.WriteLine("We found Sandy on position {0}", indexOfSandy);
  } else {
    Console.WriteLine("Sandy was not here");
  }
}
```

Comment: `i` belongs to `for` loop, so that is out of the scope here: `Console.WriteLine("We found Sandy on position {0}", i);`

Comment: @FranciscoSevilla you're right: at the beginning I didn't notice there was an index inside `Console.WriteLine` ;)